# Validation of password and confirm password in PHP Error shows all the time

Tags: php, mysql, forms, session, post

So i am trying to create a Login form and now i am at the part when i want to validate the password and the confirm password. The code i used (you can find it below) shows me everytime i submit Register button the "the password and confirm password do not match" even thought i enter the same password. any idea what should be changed in my code to remove the error?

```
<?php
session_start();

 include('includes/config.php');
include('includes/db.php');

function isUnique($email){
$query="select * from users where email ='$email'";
global $db;

 $result = $db->query($query);

if($result->num_rows>0){
return false;
}
else return true;
}

if(isset($_POST['register'])) {
$_SESSION['name']=$_POST ['name'];
$_SESSION['email']=$_POST ['email'];
$_SESSION['password']=$_POST ['password'];
$_SESSION['confirm_password']=$_POST ['confirm_password'];

if(strlen($_POST['name'])<3){
header("Location:register.php?err=".urlencode ("The name must be at least 3   characters long"));
exit();
}

else if(strlen($_POST['password']) < 5 ){
  header("Location:register.php?err=".urlencode ("The password should be at  least 5 characters"));
exit();
} 
else if(strlen($_POST['confirm_password']) < 5 ){
  header("Location:register.php?err=".urlencode ("The Confirm password     should be at least 5 characters"));
exit();
} 
else if(!isUnique($_POST['email'])){
  header("location:register.php?err=".urlencode ("Email is already in use.   Please use another one"));
exit();
}
else if($_POST['[password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']) {
     header("Location:register.php?err=".urlencode ("The password and confirm           password do not match"));
    exit();
    }

    }
    ?>
```

and here is the other part where i put the condition when the error msg should be displayed.

```
`<form action="register.php" method="post" style="margin-top:35px;">
  <h2> Register Here </h2>

  <?php
  if(isset ($_GET['err']))  { ?>

  <div class="alert alert-danger"><?php echo $_GET['err']; ?></div>
  <?php } 
  ?>`
```

Comment: The first question here is why you're writing all of this to begin with? Is it an academic project? This sort of code is extremely hard to get absolutely perfect, and anything less than that exposes you to serious security risks.

Comment: if you want check all field to validate so do not use else if use if for each field separately because in your else if case if 1st one case meet true then all below else if case will not meet to the execution

Comment: problem here. look carefully. $_POST['[password'] != $_POST['confirm_password']

Comment: **WARNING**: This has some severe [SQL injection bugs](http://bobby-tables.com/) because `$_GET` data is used inside the query. Whenever possible use **prepared statements**. These are quite straightforward to do in [`mysqli`](http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php) and [PDO](http://php.net/manual/en/pdo.prepared-statements.php) where any user-supplied data is specified with a `?` or `:name` indicator that’s later populated using `bind_param` or `execute` depending on which one you’re using.
**NEVER** put `$_POST` or `$_GET` data directly in your query.

Comment: **WARNING**: Writing your own access control layer is not easy and there are many opportunities to get it severely wrong. Please, do not write your own authentication system when any modern [development framework](http://codegeekz.com/best-php-frameworks-for-developers/) like [Laravel](http://laravel.com/) comes with a robust [authentication system](https://laravel.com/docs/5.4/authentication) built-in. At the absolute least follow [recommended security best practices](http://www.phptherightway.com/#security) and **never store passwords as plain-text**.

Answer (score 2):

You just had a little typo:

Instead of `$_POST['[password']` use `$_POST['password']`

Comment: That's one problem.

Comment: There's a bunch of red flags on this code. I'm asking what the intention is before getting overly specific.

Comment: Like the glaring SQL injection bug that, if this was a public website, would make it possible to can-opener and hijack the entire site in seconds. That sort of thing. There's also an XSS vector in the use of a param to convey error messages. I'm not trying to be mean here, but the internet is full of people who want nothing more than to wreck your life and infect your site with garbage. You have to be careful.

Comment: @tadman Yeah I know that but he was just asking why it isn't working so... xD

Comment: "Working" is a subjective thing here. If this code goes live, as-is, there's going to be problems. It's just a matter of time.